# server-clients java

Tags: java, client-server

I want to make my server able to accept messages from two clients. but something went wrong. Help needed! I tried to run same client twice, but received only one message and some errors.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Serv1 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Listner listner = new Listner();
        Thread thread = new Thread(listner);
        thread.start();

        System.out.println("thread already started");
      
        DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(8787);

        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
       
        System.out.println ("Waiting for datagram packet");

        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length); 
                
        System.out.println("about to receive packet N1");
        s.receive(p);
        
        String sentence = new String(p.getData()); 
        InetAddress IPAddress = p.getAddress(); 
        int port = p.getPort(); 
  
        System.out.println ("From: " + IPAddress + ":" + port);
        System.out.println ("Message: " + sentence);

       
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       
        receiveData = new byte[1024];
    
        System.out.println ("Waiting for datagram packet");
        p =  new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length); 
                
        System.out.println("about to receive packet N2");
      
        s.receive(p);
        sentence = new String(p.getData()); 
        IPAddress = p.getAddress(); 
        port = p.getPort(); 
}

}


class Listner implements Runnable
    { 
           
        public void run() {
        String text = null;
        while(true){
            text = null;    
        int server_port = 8787;
       
         byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length); 
        DatagramSocket s = null;
        try{
           s = new DatagramSocket(server_port);
        }catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Socket excep, port used");
        }
        try {
        s.receive(p);
       }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("IO EXcept");
            }
        text = new String(receiveData, 0, p.getLength());
        System.out.println("message = "+text);
        s.close();

    }
}

}
```

run:

> thread already started
>
> Waiting for datagram packet about to receive packet N1
>
> ```
> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
>   at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
>   at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:91)
>   at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(Socket excep, port used
> DatagramSocket.java:372)
>   at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:211)
>   at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:262)
>   at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:235)
>   at serv1.Listner.run(Listner.java:29)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at serv1.Listner.run(Listner.java:35)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
> From: /192.168.1.102:58977
> Message: hi, i am the first one
> Waiting for datagram packet
> about to receive packet N2
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 59 seconds)**strong text**
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind the same port twice. That's not how it works. You should have 1 thread listening to the port, and a pool of threads to process the requests. Whenever new information comes thought the port, you give the request data (the new info received) to a thread for processing.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating 2 `DatagramSocket`'s on the same port (8787). One is created in the main method, and the other is created in the `Listner` inner class' `run()` method.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but you either need to run the `Listner` class' DatagramSocket on a different port or pass the one created by the `main()` method to the `Listner` class.